# How to find out future timestamp value in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, timestamp, timestamp-with-timezone

I have few timestamp format

time stamp format contains YYYY MM DD hh mm ss S AM/PM CountryName/CityName(zone)

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S AM/PM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S AM/PM z
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.z
```

I want to do validation on timestamp value, If time stamp value is future value (or greater than existing) then want to show.notification message to user.

For Date format I have written following code which works to check Future date

```
DateTimeFormat df = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(dateFormat);
        Date updateDate = df.parseStrict(newDateValue);
        Date synchronizedDate = df.parseStrict(synchronizedDB_DateValue);
        boolean isFutureDate = updateDate.after(synchronizedDate);
        if (isFutureDate ) {
           // send notification
        }
        else {
            // do nothing
        }
```

**EDIT:**

**Following code only works** for timestamp format = **YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S**

```
                String timestampFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S"; // It works
                //String timestampFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S AM/PM"; 
                //String timestampFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S AM/PM z"
                //String timestampFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S z ";

                String newTimestampFormat=  timestampFormat.replaceAll("-", ".");
                newTimestampFormat = newTimestampFormat.replace("YYYY", "yyyy");
                newTimestampFormat = newTimestampFormat.replace("AM/PM", "a");

                DateTimeFormat df = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(newTimestampFormat);
                Date updateDate = df.parse(newTimeStampValue); // UPDATED VALUE = 2013.08.21 00:00:00.123

                Date synchronizedDate = df.parseStrict(synchronizedDB_DateValue); // current or old db value = 2013.07.11 00:00:00.123

                boolean isFutureTimestamp = updateDate.after(synchronizedDate);
                if (isFutureTimestamp ) {
                   // send notification
                }
                else {
                    // do nothing
                }
```

What changes I need to do for all other time-stamp format ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at [DateTimeFormat](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/shared/DateTimeFormat.html)?

Comment: @BorisBrudnoy Yes, I used for To check future data. See Updated question

Comment: Regular expressions (e.g. `myTimestampString.matches(tsRegex)`)?

Comment: @BorisBrudnoy I provided timestamp format for reference. RegEx not required. Need to find future timestamp value.

Comment: Then it's unclear to me (and, I suspect, to the other 67 who viewed your question) what is being asked here. You have a way of figuring out whether the date is in the future (`DateTimeFormat`); you have a way of validating timestamp strings (`Pattern`). What else is required?

Comment: You do realize the `Date` object can hold more information than just a date, right? So all you need to do is place your _update timestamp_ in a `Date` object and use what you already have to check against _db timestamp_ (another `Date` object) if it's future or not.

Comment: @BorisBrudnoy Please see updated question. I looked into DateTimeFormat as per your suggestion. Now updated code works for only 1 timestamp format.

Comment: Just to clarify: are you talking about `java.sql.Timestamp`, but that one doesn't have time zone information so your examples are actually invalid formats, and thus can't be parsed.

Comment: @HilbrandBouwkamp I am not talking about java.sql.Timestamp, only for provided timestamp format

Comment: May I know why your timestamp formats are not already in GWT time stamp formats? Where are these custom formats coming from?

Comment: @ADTC In our application we provided above custom formats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution and It Works :)

```
private boolean function isFutureTimestamp(){
        String gwtTimestampFormat = convertToGwtTimeStampFormat(timestampFormat); 
        // timestampFormat = YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.S AM/PM z
        // gwtTimestampFormat = yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss.S a z

        DateTimeFormat df = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(gwtTimestampFormat); 

        String newlyUpdatedTimestampValue = convertToGwtTimeStampFormat(timestampValue);
        Date updatedDateTime = df.parse(newlyUpdatedTimestampValue); 

        String currentTimestamp = convertToGwtTimeStampFormat(currentTimestampValue);
        Date currentDateTime = df.parse(currentTimestamp);

        boolean isFutureTimestamp  = updatedDateTime.after(currentDateTime);
        return isFutureTimestamp;
}

  private String convertToGwtTimeStampFormat(String gwtTimestampFormat) {

        if (gwtTimestampFormat != null && gwtTimestampFormat.length() > 20) { // "2012-12-23 23:12:32.2".length= 21
            gwtTimestampFormat = gwtTimestampFormat.replace("-", ".");
            gwtTimestampFormat = gwtTimestampFormat.replace("YYYY", "yyyy");
            gwtTimestampFormat = gwtTimestampFormat.replace("DD", "dd");
            gwtTimestampFormat = gwtTimestampFormat.replace("AM/PM", "a");
            return gwtTimestampFormat;
        }
        else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using Apache DateUtils. [(doc is here)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html)

Use parseDate method(s) as it supports a wide variety of formats and can be possibly used in many other places too.

For example while using parseDate you can feed all these time stamp patterns as a string array to the following method:

```
public static Date parseDate(String str, String[] parsePatterns) throws ParseException
```

to receive Date objects. 
And with this you can compare dates just like you compare numbers:

```
public static int truncatedCompareTo(Date date1, Date date2, int field)
```

This returns you a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first date is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

Notice that these methods are `static` so you can invoke these without needing to create a `DateUtils` objects. Just use `DateUtils.yourMethod(yourArgs)` once you have `import`ed the jar.